# ShareX NodeJS Application with NGiNX - Returning Localhost instead of domain

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx

I'm working on my old project, a custom ShareX uploader but I've come across an issue with the return from my server (nodejs).

It returns `https://localhost/u/blablah.png` when it's meant to return `https://example.com/u/blablah.png`

I'm getting the `req.hostname` upon the request to the server to upload the image,
which returns `localhost:myport` on the `rawHeaders` of the request to upload (post).
I'm starting to assume it's how my NGiNX config is setup, but I would love it if someone could point out if I am assuming correct that it is my NGiNX and not my code.

My NGiNX Config:

```yaml
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name example.com;

    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
    add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade" always;
    add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' http: https: data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'" always;
    
    location ~ /\.(?!well-known)
    {
        deny all;
    }
    
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:1337/;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding gzip;
    }
}
```

I am using Cloudflare on top of NGiNX and the UAM is set to `Essentially Off` so I know it's 100% not Cloudflare side.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, for anyone who may come across this question at a later date here is how I fixed it:

```yaml
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name example.com;

    
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
    add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade" always;
    add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' http: https: data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'" always;
    
    location ~ /\.(?!well-known)
    {
        deny all;
    }
    
    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:1337/;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding gzip;
    }
}
```

I had to add the following proxy header `proxy_set_header Host $host;` after adding that it now gives the domain.